# RuntimeException and ArithmeticException Java

Tags: java, exception

I have the following class:

```
public class TryCatchExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(1/0);
        }catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Runtime exception");
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Trying to divide by 0 is not ok.");
        } 
        finally {
            System.out.println("The program will now exit");
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler throws this error:

```
TryCatchExample.java:10: error: exception ArithmeticException has already been caught
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
          ^
1 error
```

Why does this occur? ArithmeticException is a subset of RuntimeException, so would this be throwing a RuntimeException or an ArithmeticException?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ArithmeticException` is a *subclass* of `RuntimeException`, meaning that it would already be handled by the `catch (RuntimeException e) ...` branch.

You can reorder the branches so that an `ArithmeticException` is caught first, and any other `RuntimeException` would fall through to the next branch:

```
try {
    System.out.println(1 / 0);
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println("Trying to divide by 0 is not ok.");
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    System.out.println("Runtime exception");
} finally {
    System.out.println("The program will now exit");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is because the broader exception should be caught last.Imagine an exception object to be a like a ball being dropped across different levels of a pyramid (stack of pyramid slabs).The narrower exception (subtype) is caught at the top and broader (super class) at the bottom.This wont give the compilation error.

```
 catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("Trying to divide by 0 is not ok.");
    }catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("Runtime exception");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure ArithmeticException is a subset of RuntimeException.
An arithmetic exception is an error that is thrown, when an "wrong" arithmetic situation occurs. This usually happens when
mathematical or calculation errors occur within a program during run-time.
But if you catch exception with both class, catch precedence must be top down and errors will be throws to realated exception.

Below code will throws to ArithmeticException :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            System.out.println(1/0);

        }catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Trying to divide by 0 is not ok.");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Runtime Exception");
        } 
        finally {
            System.out.println("The program will now exit");
        }
    }
```

Below code will throws to RuntimeException:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            int div = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

            int result = 1/div;

            System.out.println(result);

        }catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Trying to divide by 0 is not ok.");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Runtime Exception");
        } 
        finally {
            System.out.println("The program will now exit");
        }
    }
```